# Custom BeforeTestStarting in XUnit

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

Can I implement my custom version of `Xunit.Sdk.BeforeTestStarting` and then register it somehow? 
I want to make some prepare steps for a test case that is returned from `ClassData`. I cannot do it via `BeforeAfterTestAttribute` since I don't have access to the test case data in the attribute. But as I see, I have this access in `BeforeTestStarting` through `ITest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xunit example https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/AssemblyFixtureExample/XunitExtensions shows how this logic is expected to work